# Is it right to put a question and answer it on the same post for knowledge sharing purpose?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, instant-self-answer

I came across an application server tuning issue and I was able to solve it. I would like to share it with others on Stack Overflow. How can I do that?

Can I ask the question and then wait until Stack Overflow allows me to answer it myself? Or shall I write the case and the solution as question? Is this allowed? What is the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: answers should not be in the question. when you go to post a question further down you should be able to see a check box saying *"Answer your own question"* with a link to [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). when you click it a separate answer box should appear so when you post it'll post both at the same time

Comment: Answering your own question is *explicitly encouraged*, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Post the answer in an answer post, not in the question itself, there's a checkbox for you to tick when you create a question.

Comment: As usual note that asking solid question when you know the answer is *very hard*. Make sure to at least glance at posts in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer?sort=votes&pageSize=50 as the fact one provides an answer does not lower bar on question quality...

Comment: Also, and it might be too late but for future readers, be sure the question is on-topic. "Application server tuning" sounds an awful lot like something that would be more on-topic on [sf], unless it specifically regards programming.